# Format a number using DecimalFormat in Android

Tags: java, android, number-formatting, decimalformat

I have an EditText and I have set an input filter to only allow numbers which complains this regular expression:

```
^\\d{1,8}(\\.\\d{0,2})?$
```

that is, 8 integer and 2 fractional digits.

Note that, "0." (1 digit followed by a period) is permitted.

On edittext focus lost, I would like to read the text in the edittext and format it to show numbers grouped and removing not significant digits. For example, some scenarios:

1) if user types 1000. (with period at the end and not followed by digits), I want to display 1,000  in edittext
2) if user types 000012. or 000012 or 000012.0 or 000012.00 I want to show 12
3) If user types 1230.90 I want to display 1,230.9

so I perform below, let's say text is the number to be formatted:

```
                    // Prepare format to apply
                    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
                    format.setGroupingUsed(true);
                    format.setMaximumIntegerDigits(8);
                    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

                    // Formats the number
                    String formattedText = format.format(text);
```

I know I can do:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("########.##");
```

so when applying format using:

```
String formattedText = format.format(text);
```

It crashes.

For example I have tried to format 0. and 0.5 numbers with no luck.

How to get rid of this?

Comment: Can you post the exception? Your name 'text' is strange... format() expects a number.

Comment: yes, it was the problem. format expects a number and not a string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the `text` variable to a number first (including handling any exceptions from the parse failing). A long or a double is expected for the single parameter format overload. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#inhmethods

You might need to add some extra string logic to ensure that the cast works if "0." doesn't cast directly to a long (e.g. append an extra zero to the end of the string before the cast).

Comment: right, I have parse to double: Double.parseDouble(text) and then applied the format.format and now it works! thanks!